# How do I add specific columns from different tables onto an existing table in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an original table (TABLE 1):

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 |

I want to add column F from the table below (Table 2) onto table 1:

| A | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 29 | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | 30 | 6 | 8 |

As well as adding Column J,L and O from the table below (Table 3) onto column 1:

| A | I | J | K | L | M | N | O |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 11 | 13 | 15 | 17 | 19 | 21 |
| 2 | 10 | 12 | 14 | 16 | 18 | 20 | 22 |

How do I go about adding only the specific columns onto table 1?

Expected Result:

| A | B | C | D | F | J | L | O |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 29 | 11 | 15 | 21 |
| 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 30 | 12 | 16 | 22 |

Comment: Please include the expected result.

Comment: Yep just added it sorry for the lack of clarity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following query

```
SELECT T1.A,
       B,
       C,
       D,
       F,
       J,
       L,
       O
FROM   table1 T1
       JOIN table2 T2
         ON T1.A = T2.A
       JOIN table3 t3
         ON T1.A = T3.A
```